# HTML web page string into array or JSON in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Greetings!

Is it possible to convert an HTML string to an array or JSON using Javascript?

Something like this:

```
var stringweb = '<html><head>hi</head><body>my body</body></html>';
```

And as result, I can have this:

```
var myarray = {[html,
                  [head,
                     [hi]
                  ]
                 [etc...]
                ]}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: HTML, or XML, can't be represented (generally - the data they contain can, sometimes) as nested *lists*. At best, as nested objects with a list of `children` objects and a dictionary of attributes, but even that is very minimalistic and propably oversimplified some issues.

Comment: @delnan - in that (odd) format, it does look like the markup is retained, just in a different way.

Comment: @Pointy: But it doesn't preserve attributes.

Comment: should those values be strings? `array = {["html", ...`? or nodes somehow?

Comment: @delnan well we don't *know* that it doesn't preserve attributes; there are no attributes in the markup example supplied.

Comment: @delnan the real point is that regardless of the *output* format, step 1 -- parsing the HTML -- is probably the really hard part :-)

Comment: @Pointy: How could this format possibly store attributes (assuming of course they aren't mixed with the child nodes, which would be madness)?

Comment: @delnan - I don't know; I personally haven't seen enough of it to know. It looks like it's something invented, so I see no inherent reason that it couldn't manage to hold attributes somewhere. A ten or twenty character sample of something totally unknown doesn't tell me much or allow me to make many assumptions.

Comment: @user552669 you would probably get a more specific answer if you'd go into some detail about *exactly* what your output format is supposed to look like.

Comment: @delnan, for all we know, the OP could simply store the tagname, with the attributes (basically everything between the angle brackets) as a single string. Not saying this is the case, but I think the main question is getting the structure in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can tell from the comments above, this doesn't seem like the most robust idea... Anyhow, here is a solution that I *think* gets you what you asked for. It was fun to write, anyhow.

```
function htmlStringToArray(str) {
  var temp = document.createElement('iframe');
  temp.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(temp);
  var doc = temp.contentWindow.document;
  doc.open();
  doc.write(str);
  doc.close();

  var array = htmlNodeToArray(doc.documentElement);
  temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);
  return array;
}

function htmlNodeToArray(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == 1) {
    var array = [node.tagName];
    if (node.childNodes.length) {
      for (var i=0, child; child = node.childNodes[i]; i++) {
        if (child.nodeType == 1 || child.nodeType == 3) {
          array.push(htmlNodeToArray(child));
        }     
      }
    } else if (node.innerText) {
      array.push([node.innerText]);
    }
    return array;

  } else if (node.nodeType == 3) {
    return [node.nodeValue];
  }
}
```

I tried it out in the latest chrome, firefox and IE. Here it is running on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uqize3/7/edit

BTW your HTML string is invalid. Browsers will move "hi" from inside the `<head>` into the `<body>`. I assumed you intended to have a `<title>` in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in JavaScript, because JavaScript is a sufficiently expressive language as to allow just about anything. However, it's not going to be particularly easy: you're going to have to implement (or find) as complete an HTML parser as is necessary to recognize the particular HTML documents that you want to convert.  HTML itself is pretty complicated, and that complexity is greatly magnified by the fact that most of the world's stock of existing HTML documents are badly erroneous. Thus, if you've got well-constrained HTML that you know to be valid, or at least consistently invalid, that might make the task a little easier.

*edit* — @Hemlock points out, quite wisely, that if you're doing this in a browser (that is, if this code is going to run from inside a web page served to browsers), then you've got it a lot easier. You can hand your HTML over to the browser, perhaps as the content document for an `<iframe>` element you add to the page. If it's not too awful for the browser to parse (and browsers can cope with surprisingly weird HTML), then once the DOM is ready in the `<iframe>` you can just walk the DOM and generate whatever sort of different representation you want.

Comment: I'm assuming he's in the browser, so HTML parsing won't be needed. Then again, why the array if the DOM is present?

Comment: @Hemlock well now that's definitely a very good point, though handling *complete* HTML documents is a *little* clumsy; I guess he could dump the HTML into an `<iframe>` or something. I'll update my answer. I haven't had any coffee this morning, in my defense :)